# WooCommerce Shipping option price for delivery

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using [mx local pickup extended](https://github.com/blivic/mx-wc-local-pickup-extended) for defining local pickups location which preview as a drop down , The problem is that I cannot specify price for every location. Now I am trying to add price for every location.

Here is my function code:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_update_cart_action_cart_updated', 'mx_review_order_shipping_options_price', 10);
?>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery('select#delivery_locations').live('change', function(){

        var location = jQuery('select#delivery_locations').val();

        if (shipping_options_table == 'Miami') {
        jQuery('select#delivery_in_selected_area').val('3').change();
        }

        });
        </script>
        <?php

        }
```

But it does not work. Here is the Mx local pickup function code for shipping option.

```
/*
             * process_shipping_options function.
             */
            function process_shipping_options() {

                $options = array();

                if (isset($_POST[$this->id . '_options']))
                    $options = array_map('wc_clean', $_POST[$this->id . '_options']);

                update_option($this->options_array_label, $options);

                $this->get_shipping_options();
            }
```

Comment: Did you try the solution mentioned in their [GitHub] (https://github.com/blivic/mx-wc-local-pickup-extended) page FAQs?

Comment: No answer found there

Comment: You should add them to the Shipping Zone, set a Shipping method as Flat Rate and set the cost of shipping by editing Flat rate.

Comment: Using the same plugin? What I mean is I can only put an equal price for all the zones, but I really need that each zone has a different price. For example Doral is 2 miles away, but Sunrise is 40 miles away, they can not cost the same. I need to be able to put a different price to each zone.